# Should we merge papal-magisterium and church-magisterium?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have [papal-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papal-magisterium) and [church-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-magisterium).  What's the intended difference in usage?  Is `church-magisterium` intended to be more general than `papal-magisterium` in that the former can be used in Orthodox, LDS, or even Protestant context?  But in most use of church-magisterium so far, `catholicism` is implied.

If we want to retain both, let's add a tag description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what was implied by the tags

[papal-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papal-magisterium) means the teachings of the Pope and the Bishops of the Catholic Church

[church-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-magisterium) means "church, magisterium" like "[church-local](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-local)" means your local parish or whatnot. So it's fairly redundant in the use of the word "Church", all it's saying is that it's about ecclesiology and in particular, the highest teaching office - this is a bad form of classification.
ta
my suggestion is we disambiguate:

- [magisterial-teaching](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magisterial-teaching)

  General purpose, any denomination can use to talk about teachings that are from the elders, bishops, etc...
- [magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magisterium)

  General purpose, any denomination can use to talk about -elders, bishops, etc...
- [papal-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papal-magisterium)

  Keep for specifically Catholic questions, can use with other tags  [magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magisterium), [catholicsm](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicsm), [papacy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papacy), [magisterial-teaching](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magisterial-teaching) if desired.

Comment: So, implementing your suggestion, should we either rename `church-magisterium` to `magisterium` or make that a synonym to `magisterium` ?  And if we re-tag existing questions or have occasions to use `magisterial-teaching` and `magisterium` in future questions, we create those tags on the spot?

Comment: I think church-magisterium should be a synonym for magisterium so we don't have to do as much work, that's literally all we need to do - make sure [tag:catholicism] is on there if needed.  only add [tag:magisterial-teaching] if it's about teachings that are neither from Scripture nor Tradition.

Comment: I'd merge them all. I've never heard another denomination use the term. Presbyterians for example would not say "magisterial teachings" to refer to the teachings of elders.

Comment: Have to agree with curiousdanni.

Comment: @curiousdannii fine by me- you want to post an answer - I'll upvote it

Answer (score 0):

**Should we merge papal-magisterium and church-magisterium?**

After thinking the matter at hand, I would like to think that these tags be merged into one single tag. These are generally used only by the Catholic Church and the questions on meta seem to confirm this.

In order to avoid any future confusion I would like to propose that the tags [papal-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papal-magisterium) and [church-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-magisterium) be merge into a single tag under the heading of [catholic-church-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholic-church-magisterium)!

This is simply my own thoughts on this as other Christian denominations simply do not employ the term **magisterium**.

The Church’s magisterium is the official teaching body of the Catholic Church so [papal-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papal-magisterium) means no sense to me.

I would be okay also with the [church-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-magisterium), would prefer the tag to be renamed as [catholic-church-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholic-church-magisterium).